# How to insert (bind) DataTable to Excel Workbook (VS Excel 2010 Workbook Project)

Tags: c#, wcf, excel, ado.net

I have `WCF Service` that returns data as `DataTable` type. I want to insert this data into Excel workbook in the `Workbook_Startup` event.

What is the best way to do it?

(VS .NET 3.5 Excel 2010 Workbook Project)

---

WCF Service code:

```
public DataTable GetQuarterTargetAchievement()
{
    var dt = new DataTable("TargetAchievement");

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
    {
        using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT fld1, fld2, ... , fldN FROM dbo.ReportTable; ", conn))
        {
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
    }

    return dt;
}
```

---

Client code:

```
var dt = proxy.GetQuarterTargetAchievement();
```

Comment: What code have you tried on your own..? also what is the structure of the DataTable ..? is this returned in XML format..? if so please confirm that way I could offer you a simple solution on how to Iterate thru the XML data that the web service returned..

Comment: @DJKRAZE: I do not use XML. See changes in my post (I added the source code snippet)

Comment: what you would have to do is use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel are familiar with Interop..? if not I can post a code example and you can make the changes necessary to fit your UseCase let me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this example this should be enough to get you started
in your using section at the top add this

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

you may also have to add the Reference at the Project level as well 
make sure you order the list when you select Reference--> add--> and select the correct version of Microsoft Office Interop assembly based on the installed version you have

probably ver 12 or 14 I am guessing..

```
private static void Excel_FromDataTable(DataTable dt)
{
    // Create an Excel object and add workbook...
    Excel.ApplicationClass excel = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
    Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(true); // true for object template???

    // Add column headings...
    int iCol = 0;
    foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
    {
        iCol++;
        excel.Cells[1, iCol] = c.ColumnName;
    }
    // for each row of data...
    int iRow = 0;
    foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
    {
        iRow++;

        // add each row's cell data...
        iCol = 0;
        foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
        {
            iCol++;
            excel.Cells[iRow + 1, iCol] = r[c.ColumnName];
        }
    }

    // Global missing reference for objects we are not defining...
    object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    // If wanting to Save the workbook...
    workbook.SaveAs("MyExcelWorkBook.xls",
    Excel.XlFileFormat.xlXMLSpreadsheet, missing, missing,
    false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
    missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);

    // If wanting to make Excel visible and activate the worksheet...
    excel.Visible = true;
    Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excel.ActiveSheet;
    ((Excel._Worksheet)worksheet).Activate();

    // If wanting excel to shutdown...
    ((Excel._Application)excel).Quit();
}
```

Comment: My work day is over for today. Tomorrow I'll try to do something based on your code/ Thx!

Comment: Everything was great! Thank you! It was easier than I thought! (I added a final solution as my own answer)

Comment: That's awesome and I am glad that I was able to shed some light on it for you.. +! to you for being able to figure out an easier solution where others would have just taken the answer and not tried to understand how to refactor the code that was presented..

Answer (score 2):

Final solution:

```
var dt = proxy.GetQuarterTargetAchievement();

int
    column = 0,
    row = 0;

foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{
    this.Application.Cells[1, ++column] = col.ColumnName;
}

foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
    row++;
    column = 0;
    foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
    {
        this.Application.Cells[row + 1, ++column] = r[c.ColumnName];
    }
}
```

Comment: A long time after you did this - I was wondering if the returned data appears as pure values in Excel, or is it like an array function? Do you need to worry about the data types much?

Comment: Actually I can't remember anything neither about problem nor solution... :) Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Old format or invalid type library. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80028018 (TYPE_E_INVDATAREAD))

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = 
    excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(true); // true for object template???
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a open soure library called [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com), I found one tutorial on that. It could be helpful for you.

[DataTable to Excel](http://bytesofcode.hubpages.com/_bytes/hub/Export-DataSet-and-DataTable-to-Excel-2007-in-C)